# What is the defintion of a current-current diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, electric-current, definition, feynman-diagrams

Right now I am facing some Feynman diagram calculations and in the instructions I am reading the phrase current-current diagram appears quite often so I wanted to know:

What is the definition of a **[current-current diagram](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Feynman&as_epq=current+current+diagram)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A current-current diagram is a diagram in the diagrammatic expansion of a current-current amplitude. For the latter, see. e.g., equation (1.1) in

Keith Hamilton, The Standard Model Part II: Charged Current weak interactions I,
http://www.hep.ucl.ac.uk/~campanel/Post_Grads/2013-2014/SM-CC-Weak-Interactions-I.pdf